# НЕ запускается cog webhook disnake

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fixik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 447, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup = lib.setup
            ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cogs.event_bot.webhook' has no attribute 'setup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\micro_universe_2.0\bot.py", line 111, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{folder}.{file[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\fixik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 512, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\fixik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\common_bot_base.py", line 450, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.NoEntryPointError(key)
disnake.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.event_bot.webhook' has no 'setup' function.
```

```
import disnake
import aiohttp
from disnake import Webhook
from disnake.ext import commands


class Webhook(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(name="webhook", description="ggg")
    async def webhook(self, inter, url, text):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as webhook:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url(url=url, session=webhook)
            await webhook.send(text)
            await inter.send('gg', ephemeral=True)




def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Webhook(bot))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс и поместите в него код:

```
class Name(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot= bot
```

В этом классе можно создавать все нужные Вам команды:

```
    @commands.slash_command(name="webhook", description="ggg")
    async def webhook(self, inter, url, text):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as webhook:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url(url=url, session=webhook)
            await webhook.send(text)
            await inter.send('gg', ephemeral=True)
```

И далее **обязательно** добавьте данный класс в **Cog's**:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Name(bot))
```

Полный код:

```
class Name(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot= bot

    @commands.slash_command(name="webhook", description="ggg")
    async def webhook(self, inter, url, text):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as webhook:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url(url=url, session=webhook)
            await webhook.send(text)
            await inter.send('gg', ephemeral=True)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Name(bot))
```

Как сделать вывод **Embed'a** (по просьбе из комментариев):

```
    @commands.slash_command(name="webhook", description="ggg")
    async def webhook(self, inter, url, text):
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title="Title",
            description="Description",
            color=disnake.Colour.yellow(),
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
            )
        await inter.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

Подробнее про **Embed** в disnake: [клик](https://guide.disnake.dev/popular-topics/embeds)

Comment: спасибо!!!, а не подскажите, а как вывести сообщение embedom?

Comment: чтоб в параметры можно были писать и discription и title

Comment: Отредактировал свой ответ и ответил в нём на Ваш вопрос.